# how to show only two text boxes at a time

Tags: javascript

how to show only two textbox only by next and previous button

this is my code,in this code when i click the next button show two textbox and aging when i click show the next two textbox..totally four textbox..i want only two text box per each click.......how can I achieve that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var max=2;//highest number to go to
var currentIndex=0;
function Previous(){
  if(currentIndex>0){
    currentIndex--;
    postClick();
  }
}
function Next(){
  if(currentIndex<max){
    currentIndex++;
    document.getElementById("div").style.display="none" 
    postClick();
  }
}
function postClick(){//whatever you want to happen goes here    
  var sahan =new Array();
  sahan[currentIndex]==d;
  var d=document.getElementById("div");
  d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='name"+currentIndex+"[]'>";
  d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='topic"+currentIndex+"[]'>";        
  form1.text1.value=currentIndex;  
}
</script>

<form name="form1">
  <input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="Previous()"/>

  <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="Next()"/>

</form>
<div id="div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var max = 1; //highest number to go to
        var currentIndex = 0;
        function btnClick() {
            if (currentIndex == 0) {
                currentIndex++;
                postClick();
            }
        }

        function postClick() {//whatever you want to happen goes here

            var sahan = new Array();
            sahan[currentIndex] == d;            
            var d = document.getElementById("div");            
            d.innerHTML += "<p><input type='text' name='name" + currentIndex + "[]'>";
            d.innerHTML += "<p><input type='text' name='topic" + currentIndex + "[]'>";
            document.getElementById("div").style.display = "";  
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="btnClick()" />
        <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="btnClick()" />
        <div id="div">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: how get the text box value in array........because per each click it will show two textbox  if click the next button two time....and i entered some value in textbox.....totally four textbox value i want....so how get the value.......in array...

Comment: example:how get the following array value.................................................................when sahan[0]==d: ->name=name0[](textbox value). topic[0]=topic0[](textbox value)

Comment: I want per each click two new text box and how get the textbox value in array............because it is used to get the description for each file if i select 4 file so i want 8 text box by next and prev button.per each click also per each file only show two textbox.  finally how gwt the all text box value to store in database.......pls help me very urgent.........

Comment: you can give an id property to textbox like name1,topic1,name2,topic2 etc.. and then access the value by document.getElementById

Comment: above ur correction script again showed two textbox one by one sir per each click.....i want only show always two textbox only......i gave the id property....again it will show same...how get the textbox array value.....

Comment: so if you click next or previous button twice how many textbox do you want to show

Comment: per each click only two text box sir. and how get the  all text box values in array.........

Comment: don't call sir..  so if i ckick the button twice then 4 textboxes?

Comment: after remove the   +  it is work good.....                                              d.innerHTML  = "<p><input type='text' name='name" + currentIndex + "[]'>";
            d.innerHTML += "<p><input type='text' name='topic" + currentIndex + "[]'>";   but i could not get the all textbox values in array....how do it sir...........

Comment: like giving name to textbox give id also ie id="name"+currentIndex. and id="topic"+currentIndex. After that check the rendered page. It will contain textboxes with different id. then you can find the control by using the id

Comment: function logn()
{
  var data = $('input[name="name[]"]').map(function(){
  return this.name + '=' + this.value;
}).get().join('&');
alert(data);
 var datas = $('input[name="topic[]"]').map(function(){
  return this.name + '=' + this.value;
}).get().join('&');
alert(datas);
} this is correct or not........to get the textbox value

Comment: from where you are calling this function

Comment: from this... <form id="form1">
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="Previous()" />
        <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="btnClick()" />
            <button onclick="logn();">Get Total</button>
        <div id="div">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>

Comment: hi,                                                                 var datas = $('input[name="topic(may i mention in this area 'currentIndex')[]"]'). y i am asking i get the value in array so the currentIndex value change when i click the button so i confuse.....pls give idea.......it is very urgent work......

Comment: better try to get all textbox value starting with name. i think it will give the value

Comment: try the logn function like this                                function logn() {
            
            $('input[name^="name"]').each(function () {                
                alert(this.value);
            });
            $('input[name^="topic"]').each(function () {
                alert(this.value);
            });            
        }

Comment: @SANS780730: @mahesh: You might want to take it to [chat].

Answer (score 2):

In the postClick() function, try to remove the first "+" on line 4, i.e.:

```
d.innerHTML="...";
```

instead of

```
d.innerHTML+="...";
```

Comment: You have to remove the "+" only on the first "d.innerHTML" line.

Comment: ok...sir...it is working good.......very thank u sir......but i cant get the text box value in array......how do it sir......

Comment: how get the all textbox value in array